# How to send POST api request with the extracted details from an element using selenium+java

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, api-testing

Use case is as below.

There is a modal in a website and it contains User ID, Name and email. I want to capture those details using selenium+java and send a POST api request with the above extracted details(User ID, Name and email). How can i perform this action. Highly appreciate if someone can help with a example

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what was the result? It seems it's a question of simply making a HTTP call using any HTTP library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a high-level, the Selenium tests would scrape the data

```
...// pseudo-code
driver.url="https://sqa.stackexchange.com";
var thing1 = driver.findElement(By.Class("ws-nowrap.s-btn.s-btn__primary").text();
```

Then use an [HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3325065/1106708) to send the extracted data

```
...// code snippet (see link for full example)
var client = new HttpClient();
var params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param-1", thing1));
client.SendHttp("POST", body);
```